# How can I calculate Median, deriviation, variance etc using Arel in ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orm, arel

I have looked in Arel which is on top of ORM in ROR.

Is it any library or another function of Arel which allows me to calculate median, deriviation, variance etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR; No.**

Its the opposite - the ORM ActiveRecord is built on top of Arel which is a domain specific language for creating SQL queries. Arel adapts to many RDBMS:es.

[Arel](http://www.rubydoc.info/search/github/rails/arel?q=median) does not as far as I know have built in functions for median, deviation, variance.

I'm guessing that the main reason is that the these functions may either be totally absent or vary wildly between database systems and it would be too complicated and require too much maintenance.

You can probably use [Arels `AVG, SUM, COUNT, MIN, MAX` aggregate functions](https://github.com/rails/arel) together with a SQL string to achieve what you are looking for though.

Comment: Do u know if it is possible to write through arel nested conditions such as: A AND B AND (OR C)

Comment: Yes, its something like `table[:a].and(b).and(Arel::Nodes::Or.new(c))`